# Show first slide longer than other slides in a content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

This is a last ditch attempt to try to achieve what I need from this slider. I have implemented a jquery content slider called '[Super Simple Slider](http://supersimpleslider.com/)' on my website. I have never used this before and so far it has been super simple. However I need the first slide of the slider to display for slightly longer than all of the other slides. 10 seconds. However after much research I can not find a way to do this. Can anybody see a workaround so I can make this happen? Can I perhaps use pure JavaScript along with the jQuery to make this happen?

Below is the jQuery for the slider

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.slider').sss({
            slideShow : true, // Set to false to prevent SSS from automatically animating.
            startOn : 0, // Slide to display first. Uses array notation (0 = first slide).
            transition : 400, // Length (in milliseconds) of the fade transition.
            speed : 7000, // Slideshow speed in milliseconds.
            showNav : true // Set to false to hide navigation arrows.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to make some (easy) changes in the plugin:

**1. Add an option (to keep it configurable) : speedOnFirst (for example)**

In the plugin settings:

```
    var settings = $.extend({
        slideShow : true,
        startOn : 0,
        speed : 3500,
        speedOnFirst : 3500, // <--- HERE
        transition : 400,
        arrows : true
    }, options);
```

**2. Change the timeout in reset_timer function**

Check if target == 0 (it means it's the first slide), and then, base your timeout on settings.speedOnFirst instead of settings.speed

```
    reset_timer = settings.slideShow ? function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        speed = (0 !== target) ? settings.speed : settings.speedOnFirst; // <--- HERE
        timer = setTimeout(next_slide, speed); // <--- Change second param here
    } : $.noop;
```

**3. Call your plugin**

```
    $('.slider').sss({
        slideShow : true,
        startOn : 0, 
        transition : 400, 
        speed : 7000, 
        speedOnFirst : 10000, // <--- Delay for your first slide
        showNav : true
    });
```

[**>> See working demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtasbch8/1/)

NB: In the demo, the slides changes quickly so as you can see the difference with the first one, juste change the values with whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize the plugin to accomplish what you need.

Look at the non minified version (sss.js) and add the following logic:

Add an extra option:

```
 var settings = $.extend({
        slideShow: true,
        startOn: 0,
        speed: 3500,
        transition: 400,
        arrows: true,
        firstSlideSpeed:10000 // new setting for first slide speed
    }, options);
```

Change the slide logic:

```
reset_timer = settings.slideShow ? function () {
                    clearTimeout(timer);

                    var slideSpeed = ((target === 0) && settings.firstSlideSpeed) ? settings.firstSlideSpeed : settings.speed; // changed here
                    timer = setTimeout(next_slide, slideSpeed); // changed here
                } : $.noop;
```

This should do the trick for you.

Hope it helps!